# Case when using IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need a query to return a certain result for a certain column depending on what value the column that is being run the select statement against has.

> if the column is one of the following : I, D, U then I want to return Y
>
> if the column is one of the following : N, E, D then I want to return N
>
> ```
>                       else : I want to return NULL
> ```

I wrote the following statement but it doesn't work.

```
   SELECT HIERARCHY_TYPE,
          NODE_ID,
          NODE_TYPE,
          NODE_NAME,
          NODE_LEVEL,
          PREFERRED_ALIAS,
          PARENT_NODE_ID,
          CASE ACTIVE_INDICATOR 
             WHEN ('I' or 'U' or 'Y') THEN 'Y'
             WHEN ('D' or 'E' or 'N') THEN 'N'
             ELSE NULL
          END
     FROM MV_HIERARCHY MV;
```

Is there a way to rewrite it without using multiple OR clauses for each possible value?

Comment: You are trying simple case expression. Instead, you should be using searched case expression here. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT HIERARCHY_TYPE,
NODE_ID,
NODE_TYPE,
NODE_NAME,
NODE_LEVEL,
PREFERRED_ALIAS,
PARENT_NODE_ID,
CASE 
  WHEN ACTIVE_INDICATOR IN ('I','U','Y') THEN 'Y'
  WHEN ACTIVE_INDICATOR IN ('D','E','N') THEN 'N'
ELSE NULL
END AS ACTIVE_INDICATOR
FROM MV_HIERARCHY MV;
```

Comment: Someone suggested to add ACTIVE_INDICATOR as the new name of the column, which you'd do by adding `AS ACTIVE_INDICATOR` after the `END`.

Comment: That someone was me  X)

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE 
   WHEN ACTIVE_INDICATOR IN ('I','U','Y') THEN 'Y'
   WHEN ACTIVE_INDICATOR IN ('D', 'E', 'N') THEN 'N'
   ELSE NULL -- useless, but for readbility
END as ACTIVE_INDICATOR
```

You've got to repeat `ACTIVE_INDICATOR`, cause I don't think (may be wrong) you can use the syntax

```
CASE <field>
   WHEN IN()
```

but you can use

```
CASE
  WHEN <field> IN()
```

Comment: yeah, it is how it is supposed to be. I just made a minor alteration to mjsqu's answer. I wrote CASE ACTIVE INDICATOR WHEN < all this in stuff> and it didn't work. What I should have done is I should have written all the In stuff first and then give that column a name :)

Comment: +1 I'd just comment that the ELSE clause is unnecessary (NULL is the default anyway) but on the other hand it does perhaps add clarity.

Comment: @TonyAndrews indeed !

Answer (score 2):

```
decode(mod(nullif(instr('IDUEYN',active_indicator),0),2),0,'N',1,'Y')
```

Comment: If i were a sadist I would surely use this one X)